# How are propagators for splitting methods applied to time-dependent Hamiltonians derived?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, time-evolution

Splitting methods are defined to approximate the solution of the differential equation

$$
 y'(t) = (X+Y)y(t), \ \ \ \ \ \ \ t \in (t_0,T) \tag{1}\label{eq:1}
$$
where $X$ and $Y$ are non-commuting matrices, as follows:
$$
\prod^L_{l=1}\left(e^{ \tau a_lX}e^{ \tau b_lY}  \right) \approx e^{\tau(X+Y)} \tag{2}\label{eq:2}
$$
However,
I don't understand how this is applied to the Schrodinger equation with time-dependent Hamiltonian:
$$ u'(t) = A(t)u(t).\tag{3}\label{eq:3} $$
According to a reference,

> Simply by adding the trivial relation $\frac{d}{dt} t = 1$, this splitting method applied to (\ref{eq:3}) yields
> $$
> u_1 = \prod^L_{l=1} e^{ \tau a_lA(t_0+c_l\tau)}u_0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ c_l = \sum^l_{i=1} b_i, \tag{4}\label{eq:4}
> $$

but I do not understand where they are using $\frac{d}{dt} t = 1$, nor how they are deriving (\ref{eq:4}).

P.S.
The paper from which this is coming from can be found in the following link https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cpc.2017.07.016, but I have written the relevant parts here, as it is beyond a paywall.